# Variable in JSON stringify will not work in Rest request

Tags: javascript, json, rest, zapier, stringify

I am trying to send a request to a REST API and Im using Javascript to prepare and send it. However when I use JSON.Stringify to write out the variables needed from an object the API says Im missing required fields.

Ive tried writing the object to a string then including it in the code, and I have tried just adding JSON.Stringify to the code. Nothing works.

I build an array "Data" from posted fields in a form like so:

```
var Data = {};
var fields;
var fieldName;
var fieldValue;
var fieldValueCleaned;
var emailCleaned;
var stingForJson;
stingForJson = "";
for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){

  fields = types[i].split("=");
  fieldName = fields[0];
  fieldValue = CleanupInj(fields[1]);
  fieldValue = decodeURIComponent(fieldValue);
  fieldValueCleaned = CleanUp(fieldValue);

  Data[fieldName] = fieldValueCleaned; 

  console.log( fieldName +" : "+ fieldValueCleaned);


}
```

If I write JSON.stringify({Data}) to the console it comes our correctly:

```
{
Data: {
        "Field1": "123562374563",
        "Field2": "https://giphy.com/gifs/borat-great-success-a0h7sAqON67nO/fullscreen",
        "Field3": "https://giphy.com/gifs/haZOqHKz9tTfW/fullscreen",
        "Field4": "My@email.com",
        "Field5": "Thisisme"
    }
}
```

However when I add the variable to the code to do the request, it dosent work (as below)

```
fetch('https://MYAPIURL/v1/events', {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " : "12321321321321",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "Field1": Data.Field1,
          "Field5": Data.Field5,

        }),
  Data: JSON.stringify({Data}),
    }
     )
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  });
```

It dosent work because the values in Data are not sent to the server.

I have even tried writing the object to a string then using JSON.stringify to put it back to a json object:

```
stingForJson = JSON.stringify({Data});
stingForJson = stingForJson.slice(9,-2);
console.log("String for JSON = "+ stingForJson);

fetch('https://mc-hz56jzqd8k6ldx1sm7-s7xfbm.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events', {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "ContactKey": Data.EmailAddress,
          "EventDefinitionKey": Data.EventDefinitionKey,
     Data:{stingForJson}
        }),
```

Comment: JSON.stringify({Data}) is written as {
Data: {
        "Field1": "123562374563",
        "Field2": "https://giphy.com/gifs/borat-great-success-a0h7sAqON67nO/fullscreen",
        "Field3": "https://giphy.com/gifs/haZOqHKz9tTfW/fullscreen",
        "Field4": "My@email.com",
        "Field5": "Thisisme"
    }
} when I write it to the console

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: you do not need to use stringify while sending in a request. Send json object as it is, over the wire it will get encoded. You are converting it into string and then sending it and that is why server is not receiving desired json object.

Comment: `fetch` ignores the `Data` property you set on the object ([see the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) for a list of properties that are accepted). In other words, the value of `Data` is not sent to the server. Do you mean to send it as part of `body`? Or did you mean to write `body: JSON.stringify(Data)` instead?

Comment: Your second example should likely be: `body: JSON.stringify({ "ContactKey": Data.EmailAddress,  "EventDefinitionKey": Data.EventDefinitionKey, Data})`. `{Data:{stingForJson}}` would create an object that looks like `{Data: {stringForJSON: "\"foo\": 42"}}` which is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
body: JSON.stringify({'Data': Data}),
```

since `fetch()` doesn't support a `Data` property according to the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters

While `JSON.stringify({Data})` seems to produce the same output, I suggest to use my syntax since makes the external name (the one which the remote service expects) independent of the names of your variables.

Comment: *"I suggest to use my syntax since it doesn't depend on some magic figuring out the name of the variable."* What's magic about it? There is no good reason not to use shorthand properties. In fact, they can prevent typos in property names (e.g. `{'somtehing': something}`).

Comment: @FelixKling Hadn't seen this before which makes me think it's more of a hidden feature. I agree with your typo argument but I prefer to keep my variable names independent of the interface I'm talking to (internal vs. external names).

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. Shorthand properties have been introduced in ES2015 (ES6).